# Databricks rename a folder

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am reading the data from a folder /mnt/lake/customer where mnt/lake is the mount path referring to ADLS Gen 2, Now I would like to rename a folder from /mnt/lake/customer to /mnt/lake/customeraddress without copying the data from one folder to another folder.

I don't want to use the move copy(mv) command as it takes a lot of time to copy the data and I have almost thousands of folders that need to be renamed and the data volume is so huge.

I want to do this through data bricks does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:

Unfortunately, right now `dbutils.fs.mv` is implemented as copy + remove of original file, so it couldn't be used.  The alternative could be to use ADLS Python SDK, that has the [`rename_directory` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python#rename-or-move-a-directory) to perform that task, something like this:

```
%pip install azure-storage-file-datalake azure-identity
```

```py
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

tenant_id = "...."
client_secret = dbutils.secrets.get("scope", "client_secret")
client_id = "...."
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(
  account_url="https://<storage_acc>.dfs.core.windows.net", 
  credential=credential)
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(
  file_system="<container>")
directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("<source_dir>")
new_dir_name = "abc2"
directory_client.rename_directory(
   new_name=directory_client.file_system_name + '/' + new_dir_name)
```

Original answer, before correction:
Mount is just an entry in some internal database that maps the name to the actual location of the data. If you want to rename mount point, just unmount it with [dbutils.fs.unmount("/mnt/mount-name")](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutils-fs-unmount) and mount it again with [dbutils.fs.mount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#---mount-adls-gen2-storage) using the new name (you need to have credentials for service principal):

```py
dbutils.fs.unmount("/mnt/lake/customer")
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>"),
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}

# Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/lake/customeraddress",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

Comment: It is not about renaming a mount path, it is renaming a folder name that exists in Azure Data lake Gen2 through Databricks.